# Custom asyncio executor

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I need to implement the algorithm using asyncio with the following conditions (behaviour):

1. check the list of arguments is not empty, if empty finish execution
2. pop next argument from the list of arguments create coroutine with
3. this argument and schedule it for execution "at same time" can't be
4. executed no more than 'async_level' coroutines when coroutine finish
5. execution -> go to the step 1

It is necessary not to plan to complete all tasks at once (as with asyncio.gather), but to do it in parts. When the next task finishes execution, a new one takes its place.

I tried to do it with asyncio.as_completed() but it doesn't actually work as expected:

```
async_level = 4
params_count = 10
params = [i for i in range(1, params_count + 1)]

tasks = {asyncio.create_task(job(param)) for param in params[0: async_level]}
params = iter(params[async_level:])

while True:
    # NOTE: It wont work, because you can't add task in 'tasks' after 'as_completed' is invoked, so execution actually ends when the last coroutine in the 'as_completed' ends
    for task in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        print(f"len(tasks) = {len(tasks)}")
        await task

        try:
            param = next(params)
            tasks.add(asyncio.create_task(job(param)))
        except StopIteration:
            print("StopIteration")

    break
```

Also, I tried to implement it using asyncio.BoundedSemaphore, but first two conditions are not met:

```
async_level = 4
params_count = 10
params = [i for i in range(1, params_count + 1)]

async def semaphore_job(name, _asyncio_semaphore):
    async with _asyncio_semaphore:
        await job(name)

asyncio_semaphore = asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(async_level)
jobs = []
# NOTE: This variant schedule all jobs at ones and it's significant drawback because the count of jobs can be overwhelmed
for param in params:
    jobs.append(asyncio.ensure_future(semaphore_job(param, asyncio_semaphore)))
await asyncio.gather(*jobs)
```

I would be grateful for any of your help.

Comment: I don't understand where precisely is the problem with the semaphore solution you presented. I understand that it schedules all the jobs in advance, but most of them immediately suspend on the semaphore, before getting to the actual job. A task is a relatively small Python object, so unless you have millions of them, they shouldn't overwhelm asyncio. Did you have a specific problem with that version, or were you attempting to optimize memory usage by not creating the jobs in advance?

Comment: Not millions, but hundreds of thousands. I understand that I can use the BoundedSemaphore version, but I didn't want to schedule all tasks in advance, but only if necessary. It seemed me wild to use a hundreds of megabytes of RAM (Task == 200 byte) for storing tasks and I looked for a more elegance solution.

Comment: Fair enough, I just wanted to check what was wrong with the "obvious" solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found the solution myself:

```
import asyncio
from typing import Callable
from random import randrange
from asyncio import Semaphore, ensure_future, get_event_loop


async def job(name, time_range=10):
    timeout = randrange(time_range)
    print(f"Task '{name}' started with timeout {timeout}")
    await asyncio.sleep(timeout)
    print(f"Task '{name}' finished")
    return name


async def custom_executor(func: Callable, args: list, async_level: int = 4):
    """ Asynchronously executes no more that 'async_level' callables specified by 'func' with corresponding 'args' """
    loop = get_event_loop()
    sync = Semaphore()
    todo = set(args)
    doing = set()

    def _schedule_task():
        if todo:
            arg = todo.pop()
            fr = func(*arg) if isinstance(arg, (tuple, list, set)) else func(arg)
            f = ensure_future(fr, loop=loop)
            f.add_done_callback(_on_completion)
            doing.add(f)

    def _on_completion(f):
        doing.remove(f)
        sync.release()
        _schedule_task()

    for _ in range(min(async_level, len(todo))):
        _schedule_task()

    while True:
        if not doing:
            break

        await sync.acquire()


async def main():
    await custom_executor(job, [(1, 3), 7, (8, 2), 12, 5])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

But if you know a better way, please share!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fixed number of workers and give them tasks using a queue. It's a bit shorter and I find it a bit easier to reason about than your code, which uses callbacks. But YMMV.

```
async def custom_executor(func, args, async_level=4):
    queue = asyncio.Queue(1)
    async def worker():
        while True:
            arg = await queue.get()
            fr = func(*arg) if isinstance(arg, (tuple, list, set)) else func(arg)
            await fr
            queue.task_done()

    # create the workers
    workers = [asyncio.create_task(worker()) for _ in range(async_level)]

    # Feed the workers tasks. Since the queue is bounded, this will also
    # wait for previous tasks to finish, similar to what you wanted to
    # achieve with as_completed().
    for x in args:
        await queue.put(x)
    await queue.join()  # wait for the remaining tasks to finish

    # cancel the now-idle workers
    for w in workers:
        w.cancel()
```